# FactoryGirl: Creating dynamic factories with parameters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I have three factories that i  want to DRY up. They look like this:

```
factory :sequenced_stamps_by_years, class: Stamp do
  ...
  sequence(:day_date) { |n| n.years.ago }
end

factory :sequenced_stamps_by_months, class: Stamp do
  ...
  sequence(:day_date) { |n| n.months.ago }
end

factory :sequenced_stamps_by_weeks, class: Stamp do
  ...
  sequence(:day_date) { |n| n.weeks.ago }
end
```

How can i dry this up? I want to be able to create them something like this:

```
FactoryGirl.create_list(:sequenced_stamps_by_x, 4, x: "weeks") ## <- So that i can decide whether I want weeks, days, years, or months ago.
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Could you describe the output you want?

Comment: I want x amount of Stamp-objects, and :day_date's date should be x amounts of weeks, years, or months back in time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you don't favor the inheritance approach, there is an alternative using a parameter. Basically:

```
factory :stamps do
  ignore do
    interval :years # possible values => :years, :months, :weeks
  end

  sequence(:date_date) { |n| n.send(interval).ago }

  # rest of attributes here
end
```

Now you can do:

```
FactoryGirl.create(:stamps, :interval => :months)
```

or

```
FactoryGirl.create(:stamps)
```

which defaults to years.

All this you can find in [Factory Girl transient attributes](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#transient-attributes)

Comment: Looks like the syntax has been updated to `transient do` instead of `ignore do`. Works like a charm.

Comment: For me, this answer explained so much, so simply, I had to give you an extra '+1' on your other answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Factories can inherit from other factories. Therefore you can do something like:

```
factory :stamps do
  # common attributes here
  .....

  factory: sequenced_stamps_by_years do
    sequence(:day_date) { |n| n.years.ago }
  end
  factory: sequenced_stamps_by_months do
    sequence(:day_date) { |n| n.months.ago }
  end
  factory: sequenced_stamps_by_weeks do
    sequence(:day_date) { |n| n.weeks.ago }
  end
 end
```

Comment: Thanks! This is definitely better, but is there a way i can set week, month, or years in as a parameter? So that i can just create one dynamic factory instead of three?

Comment: Added another response that uses a parameter